# How to access a installed gem inside travis

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I have created a rubygem which can installed by:
* gem install youtube_dlhelper
* cd .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/youtube_dlhelper-0.1.9.5
* rake setup

I set up my .travis.yml:
    os:
      -linux

```
dist: trusty

language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.2.1
  - 2.2.2

env:
  global:
    - JRUBY_OPTS=-Xcext.enabled=true
    - CI=true
    - TRAVIS=true
    - LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    - LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

before_script:
  - cd $GEM_HOME/gems/youtube_dlhelper-0.1.9.5
  - rake setup

after_success:
  - CI=true TRAVIS=true coveralls --verbose

notifications:
  email:
    - samannsml@directbox.com
```

But travis don't find the directory. Also i tried:

```
before_script:
        - cd $GEM_HOME/gems
        - ls
```

But it looks like the directory is empty.

Maybe anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the ci uses the git code directly. So it is enough to use

before_script:
        - rake setup

So it runs :-)